# Invoke-WebRequest "host unknown" in powershell version 7.2, 5.1 did work

Tags: powershell-7.2

I use a script in our intranet with ps 5.1:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri http://intra.mycompany.com/mysite
```

updating to powershell 7.2 it stopped working

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseDefaultCredentials -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication -Uri http://intra.mycompany.com/mysite
```

It says "Invoke-WebRequest: The given host is unknown." How can I make this http-request work in ps 7?

Comment: Are you placing the URI in quotes? e.g.

Invoke-WebRequest -UseDefaultCredentials -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication -Uri 'http://intra.mycompany.com/mysite'

Comment: ' or " makes no difference - same 'host unknown' result.